# Getting import error while installing odoo 15

Tags: odoo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo151/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 1196, in load_server_wide_modules
    odoo.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/opt/odoo151/odoo/odoo/modules/module.py", line 396, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/opt/odoo151/odoo/odoo/addons/base/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/opt/odoo151/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import ir_mail_server
  File "/opt/odoo151/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_mail_server.py", line 23, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import PyOpenSSLContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 62, in <module>
    from ..packages import six

ImportError: cannot import name 'six'
```

I was getting above error while trying to install odoo 15

I have already tried this command for installing six package->

```
sudo apt-
get install python-six
```

..but getting same error again and again even after installing 'six' package.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `six` packages

> pip3 install six

OR

> pip install six

Comment: I have already try this commands...but getting same error cannot import name 'six'

Comment: It seems your package installed in wrong place. Please verify your all package location and verify `six` package.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you updated urllib3. After upgrading urllib, I was able to resolve this. Please try it once:

```
sudo pip3 install urllib3 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following command:

`sudo -H pip3 install firebase_admin pyOpenSSL`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following commands from inside your odoo directoty.

```
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```